# openacc - alias for an array results in "Cannot determine bounds for array" error

Tags: alias, openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

I have an array of size N on my host. I will transfer it to my device and then I try to assign an alias to it and use that. But, I get a "Cannot determine bounds for array" **compilation error**.

Example:

```
#include <openacc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 1000


int main() {
    double *ar = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        ar[i] = (i+1) * 1.0;

    #pragma acc data copy(ar[0:N])
    #pragma acc parallel
    {
        ar[90] = 29;

        double *br = ar;
        br[6] = 91;
    }

    ar[129] = 0.154;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        if(ar[i] != (i+1) * 1.0)
            printf("ERROR: %d - %.3f\n", i, ar[i]);

    free(ar);

    return 0;
}
```

Above code will result in following error:

`PGC-S-0155-Cannot determine bounds for array br (array.c: 15)`

Even, if I try to be more specific and try this `double *br = &ar[0];`, the same thing happens.

I am using PGI 16.5 64-bit version with CUDA 7.5 on a cc20 device.

Since I am using a valid array, the aliasing should not be a problem, right? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scoping issue where the compiler isn't retaining that "br" is local to the parallel region.  Since I work for PGI, I added a problem report (TPR#22760) and sent it to our compiler engineers for further evaluation.

Comment: So, you think it might work on current naive implementation of GCC or any other? I am just asking.

Comment: I'm not sure about GNU.  Note that if you put "br" declaration inside a parallel for loop, the scoping will be correct.  Is there are reason why you're putting the declaration in a bare parallel region?  I'm not clear on the use case given this is executed sequentially.

Comment: The reason behind it is the fact that if I bring the declaration outside of `#pragma` I need to specify the size of pointer, which in some cases I don't know yet. I am just using it as a placeholder in the parallel region.

Comment: Hey Mat. Is this issue resolved? I am working on something that I need this feature. I was wondering whether it has been fixed or not. I was able to compile and run above code with OpenACC-enabled GCC without any errors. I am eager to see it in PGI. Also, how can I check the status of your report (TPR#22760)? Thanks.